# How to save a uiimageview on top of another uiimageview (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, swift3, uiimageview

Right Now I have two image views. All the button does is save the photo with the red box over the blue box and it will save image2 in the blue box and image1 in the red box. I would like red box to be saved over the blue box in just the small bottom right section of the blue box. Just like a lower third you see on tv ]]

[image]
     import UIKit

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {


var image1 = UIImage(named: "f.jpg")
var image2 = UIImage(named: "l.jpg")
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.




}
func saveImage(image1:UIImage, image2:UIImage) -> UIImage {

    let size1 = image1.size
    let size2 = image2.size

    let origin = CGPoint(x: size1.width-size2.width, y: size1.height - size2.height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size2, false, 0.0)

    image1.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size1))
    image2.draw(in: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size2))

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
}
@IBAction func d(_ sender: Any) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(saveImage(image1:image1!, image2:image2!), self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}
func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        // we got back an error!
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }

 }}
```

[image: Photo that is saved in photo library]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have in saveImage function should work - ***assuming*** that image1 is larger than image2, however, if image1 and image2 are the same sizes then you will only see the second image because the origin will become (0,0). So in other words, if image1 and image2 are both 300x300, then image2 draws over image1.

The IBAction method appears to be wired up correctly and I believe what you are missing is some logic to resize the second image. Use the code below to guide you, the math will likely change depending on what ratio of image1 to image2 you're looking for.

```
func cropImageIntoQuarterSquare(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    let originalImageSize: CGSize = image.size
    let smallImageSize = CGSize(width: (originalImageSize.width / 4), height: (originalImageSize.height / 4))

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(smallImageSize)
    image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)
    let imageResult = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return imageResult
}
```

If you incorporate the resizing code then your IBAction might look something like this:

```
@IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let croppedImage = cropImageIntoQuarterSquare(image: image2),
        let combinedImage = saveImage(image1: image1, image2: croppedImage) else {
            // handle the error
            return
    }

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(combinedImage, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}

func saveImage(image1: UIImage, image2: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    let size1 = image1.size
    let size2 = image2.size
    let origin = CGPoint(x: size1.width - size2.width, y: size1.height - size2.height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size1)
    image1.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size1))
    image2.draw(in: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size2))
    let combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return combinedImage
}

func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        // we got back an error!
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Edit: Forgot to give credit to @Peter Tao for some of the code he already provided - and the link from hackingwithswift.com he provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// returns a new image where image2 in the bottom right corner of image1

func saveImage(image1:UIImage, image2:UIImage) -> UIImage {

    let size1 = image1.size
    let size2 = image2.size

    let origin = CGPoint(x: size1.width-size2.width, y: size1.height - size2.height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size1, false, 0.0)

    image1.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size1))
    image2.draw(in: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size2))

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
}
```

This is the output

[image]

To use this function to save to the photo album:

```
@IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(saveImage(image1:image1, image2:image2), self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}


func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        // we got back an error!
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
}
```

From [this tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/13/5/saving-to-the-ios-photo-library)

Comment: what would I put in the action button?

Comment: The action button can go anywhere on the screen. I am not sure if I understand your question completely. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: the code uses the button to save the photo to photo Gallery. I have to have the button run some function so the photo will be saved. I tried  to insert saveImage into the takePhoto button but that does not work. Do I even need a action button.

Comment: @JasonStone edited the answer. Let me know if that works!

Comment: its getting close but the photo being saved is not displaying both images. I have changed my code with your code. My first image is what is in the simulator the 2nd image is whats being saved. I would like the image to be saved exactly how it is displayed in the first photo, with it being a full screen photo. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hmm, where is the top image coming from? Is that displayed in an ImageView?

Comment: the top image is from the Xcode simulator its using two uiimageviews. I manually placed the images from the drop down menu in the storyboard board editor. The top picture is from the Xcode simulator when the code is built and run.