# how to use this function to save two uiimageviews together (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, swift3, uiimageview

Someone gave me the function below

```
func saveImage(image1:UIImage, image2:UIImage) -> UIImage {

let size1 = image1.size
let size2 = image2.size

let origin = CGPoint(x: size1.width-size2.width, y: size1.height - size2.height)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size1, false, 0.0)

image1.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size1))
image2.draw(in: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size2))

let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
return newImage!}
```

This person said it would save to image views together with image view 1 being printed over image view 2 in the small right hand section. The problem is that I don't know how to call this function with the code i Have.

```
import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

var image1 = UIImage(named: "hat.jpg")
var image2 = UIImage(named: "cat.jpg")

 override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a  nib.
  }


 @IBAction func TakePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
  }}
```

I am trying to get my two imageviews to be save like this ignore the button. I am just trying to get this to look like lower 3rds you would see on cnn. [image]

Comment: Why are you posting a new question instead of completing [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461637/how-to-save-a-uiimageview-on-top-of-another-uiimageview-swift3)?

Comment: @rmaddy because the user has not responded. I am sorry I am just trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide much information, but I'll take a stab at it.

Let's assume the two images you want to display are the properties `image1` (hat.jpg) and `image2` (cat.jpg) from your `ViewController` class.

Let's further assume that the function `saveImage` is inside your `ViewController` class.

Let's further assume that the point in time when you wish to perform this task is whenever `TakePhoto` is called.

Let's further assume that you know what to do with the final image once you have it.

If these are all true, then:

```
 @IBAction func TakePhoto(_ sender: Any)
 {
     let newImage = saveImage(image1: image1, image2: image2)
     // Do something with 'newImage'
 }
```

A quick note about the `saveImage` function that was provided to you: `image2` will be aligned to (and overlaid upon) the bottom-right corner of `image1`. If `image2` (cat.jpg) is larger than `image1` (hat.jpg) then your cat will not be in the hat, but rather will completely cover the hat. This can be the case in either direction (width or height or both.)

Just ensure that your two images (cat/hat) are both proportionally sized to each other.